# Compiling Error in Texmaker 4.4.1

Tags: compiling

I installed MikeTex 2.9 and Texmaker 4.4.1 on windows 7. However, when I compile Tex document it gives following error:

```
**Could not start the Command pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex**
```

What should I do next

Comment: Have you installed MikTeX first? Seems like pdflatex cannot be found, but MikTeX should set the appropriate paths by defualt. I am not a MikTeX user though, so i am just guessing.

Comment: I'm a MiKTeX user, and I confirm Johannes_B's comment: MiKTeX has to be installed *before* TeXmaker. Try unstalling and re-installing TeXmaker.

Comment: @Bernard, that is not true. See my answer.

Comment: @daleif What is your answer.

Comment: It is listed below

Comment: @Ehsa, please update your question with the comment you made on Dolphins answer. You might want to be a bit more specific. For example specify which version of Windows you are using. Did the miktex installation give any errors. Did you install as administrator? Is latex recognized as a program if you run it from a dos prompt.

Comment: @daleif I am using 64 bit windows 7 OS. MikeTex did not give any errors during installation. I installed it as admin.

Comment: @Ehsa, ok, next step, try starting a dos prompt (it is usually under accessories), and then run the command `latex`. What happens?

Comment: Running latex command in dos prompt gives "This is pdfTex, version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 <MikTex 2.9 64-bit>

Comment: Ahh, interesting. In my test I used the 32-bit MikTeX on my 64-bit system (there is no real gain in using 64-bit binaries when it comes to LaTeX). What does the command `path` give you? That answer might be a bit long, so please update your question witrh that information.

Comment: Besides showing paths to other program it shows following at the end C:\Program Files \miketex\miktex\bin\x64\

Comment: That looks ok. Just for the fun of it, have you rebooted windows?

Comment: yes  i rebooted it, but the error was same.  Should I install 32 bit Miketex without uninstalling 64 bit.

Comment: No idea. If you install the 32 bit, then reinstall the 64-bit. Again for fun. The document you are trying to compile in TeXMaker, can it be compiled via the dos prompt?

Comment: How to compile it using dos prompt? Actually in the previous comment, I meant can I have both 32 bit and 64 bit version installed?

Comment: Find the folder that holds your file, right click on that folder while holding down the Shift key. Then you get extra featues, one of these is to start a dos promt on this given folder. Then run `pdflatex` on the file.

Comment: I followed the steps and used pdflatex aa.tex, it gives "The memory dump file could not be found" besides showing the version of Miketex

Comment: Ok, then something is really wrong. In the miktex maintenance menu (probably the admin one, start with admin rights), try (1) Rebuid filename datebase and (2) rebuild formats.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use LaTeX you need two things:

1. A LaTeX installation, this includes the LaTeX format it self and all the packages
2. You need an editor, like TeXMaker or TeXStudio.

If you only have installed an editor, then you are still missing a LaTeX installation. And you get the error you mention (it is actually worse if you use TexStudio, there it only warns that it cannot find a log file).

---

As an extra comment to @Dolhpin and @Bernard. It tried the following in a clean Win 7 (VM)

1. Installed TeXMaker and TeXStudio, started both editors on a simple *hellow word* doc, and left them running
2. Installed miktex basic
3. When I go back to the two editors the was running before miktex was installed we see the error the OP was mentioning. But if I stopped TeXMaker and TeXStudio and started them again, then LaTeX compiles just fine.

Conclusion: TeMaker and TeXStuido rely on the PATH variable. If that value changes when the program is running, the program will never know.

So you do *not* have to reinstall miktex or TeXMaker. Just install MikTeX (or TeX Live) and restart TeXMaker.

---

You can see the same effect in the dos prompt. Open a dos prompt before MikTeX is installed and run the command: `path`. That will list the system path as it was when the dos promt was started. Leave it open and re-ruin `path` after MikTeX has been installed. It will report the same PATH.

Now start a *new* dos prompt, and run `path`, it now lists the updated PATH.

Comment: Nice. In the old days, one had to reinstall. Quite sure. I think the paths were hardlinked in TeXmaker.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I think there have been several of those. And at least the last time (several years ago) that I tried TeXnicCenter, one had to run a wizard and explicitly tell it where the binary folder for the LaTeX dist was. Most users did not know where that folder was.

Comment: Ah, TeXnicCenter. I hate that editor. :-)